# Task Scheduler with Powershell Sharepoint ps1

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks

I am facing an issue using the Task Scheduler to run a Sharepoint Powershell script. 
I'm using the following in the Task Scheduler : 
-Command "& 'C:\Users\crpmcr\Desktop\Upload\Script.ps1'"

This is the resume of my script :

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

New-Item "[PATH]" -type file
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "[PATH]"
$stream.WriteLine("Message Example")

Try{
    $web = Get-SPWeb "[WebApplicationUrl]"
}
Catch{
    $stream.WriteLine("Error")
}
$stream.close()
```

If i remove the line in the try, i get the Message Example line in my new file. But it seems that the line in the try does make everything break. My file is created but it's empty. Even if some text has been added before. Also the rest of my script using the web is not working obviously.

Any idea about what my problem could be ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PowerShell from

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Try changing it to

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

And see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hello Notjustme, I tried your solution but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Yeah, that really should have been a comment rather than answer since it was a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. My script was creating a file for logs and when i clicked in it it was empty. So i thought there was an issue but in fact it's because the line GetSP-web take severals seconds on my server. so it blocks the writing while it's looking for the web. 10 seconds later my file had the lines added. Obviously i was too fast and had to wait longer to see the result.